# Javascript debugging: Printing out the element retrieved from a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get an HTML element with a jQuery selector and print out all its contents (either in an alert or console debug). Something like this...

```
 <div class="mydiv">Hello is it me you are looking for?</div>
 <script>
    alert("But I still haven't found what I am looking for " + $("#mydiv").html());
  </script>
```

I also tried printElement as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530192/print-div-content-by-jquery), but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here is a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abuMariam/zLg47eyt/#&togetherjs=bzMx9vFVvv).

Comment: try $(".mydiv").html() instead.  "#" is to query on an id and "." is for classes

Comment: *Note:* You need to include jQuery in your fiddle, there is an option on the top-left hand when clicking the `JavaScript` button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`#`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) is the id selector. You have a class (`<div class="mydiv">`) so you need to use the class selector [`.`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
alert("But I still haven't found what I am looking for " + $(".mydiv").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content for which you want to print HTML element.

```
<div id="myHtml">
  <div class="mydiv">Hello is it me you are looking for?</div>
</div>

<script>
  alert($("#myHtml").html())
</script>
```